Can't connect to postgres from docker
I can connect to my DB from terminal on my PC:
psql postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:6432/feast_backend_db
psql (15.8 (Homebrew), server 15.3 (Debian 15.3-1.pgdg120+1))
Type "help" for help.

feast_backend_db=# 
feast_backend_db=# \dn
      List of schemas
  Name  |       Owner       
--------+-------------------
 public | pg_database_owner
(1 row)

I want to use this DB in my feast-based application
My application config:
# feature_store.yaml

project: test_online_project
registry:
  registry_type: sql
  path: "postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:6432/feast_backend_db"
  cache_ttl_seconds: 3
provider: local

online_store:
    type: postgres
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 6432
    database: feast_backend_db
    db_schema: public
    user: postgres
    password: postgres
entity_key_serialization_version: 2
offline_store:
  type: spark

I am building my application with help of this dockerfile
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app


RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y install netcat gcc g++ postgresql \
  && apt-get clean

COPY . .

RUN python3 -m pip install dist/feast-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl

CMD ["feast", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "6566", "--type", "http"]

I have an error
docker run  feast_server:v1  


Feast is an open source project that collects anonymized error reporting and usage statistics. To opt out or learn more see https://docs.feast.dev/reference/usage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3250, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 310, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 868, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 476, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 371, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 666, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 590, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 597, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 6432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
...



My DB is started with help of docker-compose

  db:
    image: postgres:15.3
    expose:
      - 6432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=feast_backend_db
    ports:
      - "6432:6432"
    command: -p 6432


Could you please try this: path: "postgresql://postgres:postgres@host.docker.internal:6432/feast_backend_db" and also the host: host.docker.internal

Is your database running on the host or in a container? If it's in a container, is it on the same bridge network as your application?

My DB is started with help of docker-compose

localhost or 127.0.0.1 in Docker generally means "the current container".  If you start both the application and database in the same Compose file (recommended) then you can use the Compose service name as a host name, plus the standard PostgreSQL port 5432; db:5432.  (Do not try to change the database internal port using command: or use the obsolete expose: option, and don't try to connect to other containers using host.docker.internal.)
